# Required steps for Domain Name Setup

Tags: dns

What are the required steps (i.e. purchase of a domain, etc.) to get a DNS domain (i.e. foobar.com) to point to any static and public IP (i.e. 100.101.102.103)?

If I hosted a DNS server myself (at the IP 100.101.102.103), would anyone else actually be able to connect to my server, given that no other DNS server would know about me.

Comment: Are you asking for the steps on how to point your new domain name to an IP or the entire process of purchase?

Comment: Yes, as I have no clue how that works (both on the user- and the technical side)

Comment: Have you selected a domain name provider? Most answers will be determined by people's preference for this so would be useful if you had one in mind.

Comment: Does it really depend that heavily on a domain-name provider? I didn't know that. And no, I do not have any in mind.

Comment: The process each site will use should be [mostly] the same, but their layout will differ. I shall post the process I used for a simple domain through GoDaddy and see if this helps you.

Comment: Variant 1: "Order a server with domain" -> Everything is set up by the ISP.  Variant 2: "Order a domain with IP service" (usually costs extra): You do it with the web service there.  ... Variant infinity: Buy some servers, setup DNS on them, have them running, register them as DNS for domains.  Variant infinity+1: Create a fab which produces chips .. grave some computers out of them.  To to ripe.net and become AS.  etc. pp.

Comment: @DavidStockinger Rest assured that, when you choose a provider, they will have *plenty* of documentation in the help section telling you how to give them money. ;-)

Comment: @jpaugh Wouldn't all the documentation my boss gives me be in japanese...but that's another story to be told ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of registrar's allow you to change the DNS records.

So, regardless of who you register with, log on to their site (the registrar's site) and you should get to their control panel, where you can edit the DNS settings.

Within the DNS settings, there are many options, such as A records, MX records etc.

You need to edit the A record and simply enter the IP address you want it to get to.

You also mention what happens if you host the DNS yourself. Well I've done this (due to the registrar having certain faults). I logged onto to the registrar website and simply  changed the NS records (which they also referred to as Glue records). Pointing them to my own server (in the same way as pointing the A record) was all that was needed. Since I had already set up the DNS records on my own server, it just worked!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of my setup I use  [GoDaddy](https://uk.godaddy.com/) for my domain purchases. Once you have created an account and purchased a domain you go onto:

Hi [Your Name] > Manage Account > Domains > Launch > DNS Zone File

Point the A (Host) at whatever IP you would like and wait for them to process it. Should be done in around 24 hours. Since I don't need anything else I don't change any other information except for a forwarding rule under the Settings tab.

I suspect this is about as simple as you can get.

EDIT: Based on your comments I gather you aren't trying to set up a domain name server (DNS) and instead wish to point a domain at an IP. A DNS provides a very specific thing in the process of the web in the same way a WINS server provides a process to NetBIOS in a Windows network. See  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) for an overview of DNS.